# how to display notification for every record added in db ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, push-notification

I have two web pages

1. Display record
2. Insert record

Whenever I add record I want a notification on homepage saying 3 records are added. Just like FB notifying number 3 for 3 new notifications.

I am completely blank on this one.

Can you guys please refer me to some tutorials and links?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achived using notifications via SignalR.

Check out SignalR at http://signalr.net and http://www.asp.net/signalr

Comment: am not using MVC. did not find any tutorial using signalr

Comment: Asp.NET MVC is not prerequisite for SignalR, please check added URL.

Comment: +1 This is the simplest way to go. It works with MVC and Web Forms asp.net